# Употребление слова в переносном значении

Tags: кавычки

Нужны ли повторно употреблять кавычки (этим "ролям")?

Так, в документах упомянутого выше форума сформирован перечень «ролей» в процессах управления активами и соответствующих этим ролям компетенций.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для постановления кавычек нет оснований.